# How can I download images from web pages with wget in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line, downloads, wget

I'm trying to download images from a web page using `wget` in terminal but it's not working correctly. I want all my images to get saved in a folder. But it's not working. The command I'm using is:

```
wget -r -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you check `man wget` and look at the option `--output-document=`

I hope this helps